# Virtualized infrastructure with R630s

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, hyper-v, storage

I was recently assigned to a new project where I will have to build new virtualized infrastructure using Dell R630 hosts with 32GB RAM, E5 2600 v4 CPU and 12 10k SAS drives in each. I also have 2DP 10G Mellanox cards in each host and 2 Mellanox switches.

What I need to decide is what storage vendor do I go with, S2D or VMware Virtual SAN. I think that VMware will be better as I have more experience using and managing it, also S2D was released recently, so no one really had much time to test it in production.

Couple of days ago, I was talking about this project with my colleague and he told me to also look at StarWind and HPE as they would do pretty much the same thing but cheaper and I started my research. Unfortunately, I did not find any useful information and decided to ask people who tried either of these solutions to share their thoughts.

Appreciate the time spent on reading this and letting me know what you think?

UPD: Yes, I need to build shared storage between servers.

A coulpe of questions in addition:

- I have only 2x servers, and I heard that some of the solutions I've mentioned before require a witness server? Can I go with only 2 servers and nothing more?
- Are there any difficulties using Infiniband cards to build shared storage between servers? (Again, question about products listed above)

Comment: You've asked this question already. Again, VMware Virtual SAN and Storage Spaces Direct are not storage vendors. They're storage technologies. What are you trying to do, use local storage as shared storage for your virtualization hosts?